# Split using regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I wan to split file name from the given file using regex function re.split.Please find the details below:

```
SVC_DC = 'JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar"
```

My solution:

```
import regex as re
ans=re.split(os.sep,SVC_DC)
```

Error: `re.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: You don't want to use `regex` for this, especially not on Windows. Furthermore, `os.sep` is the wrong character (path seperator, not file name extension seperator). Try `SVC_DC.split(".")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your failure are details concerning regular expressions,
namely the quotation issue.

E.g. under Windows `os.sep` = `'\\'`, i.e. a **single** backslash.

But the backslash in regex has special meaning, just to escape special characters,
so in order to use it **literally**, you have to write it **twice**.

Try the following code:

```
import re
import os

SVC_DC = 'JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar'
print(re.split(os.sep * 2, SVC_DC))
```

The result is:

```
['JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar']
```

As the source string does not contain any backslashes, the result
is a list containing only one item (the whole source string).

### Edit

To make the regex working under **both** Windows and Unix, you can try:

```
print(re.split('\\' + os.sep, SVC_DC))
```

Note that this regex contains:

- a **hard-coded** backslash as the escape character,
- the path separator used in the current operating system.

Note that the **forward** slash (in Unix case) does not require quotation,
but using quotation here is still acceptable (not needed, but working).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a filename, regexes are not your answer.

Python has the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) dedicated to handling filepaths, and its objects, besides having methods to get the isolated filename handlign all possible corner-cases, also have methods to open, list files, and do everything one normally does to a file.

To get the base filename from a path, just use its automatic properties:

```
In [1]: import pathlib

In [2]: name = pathlib.Path("/home/user/JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar")

In [3]: name.name
Out[3]: 'JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar'

In [4]: name.parent
Out[4]: PosixPath('/home/user')
```

Otherwise, even if you would not use `pathlib`, os.path.sep being a single character, there would be no advantage in using `re.split` at all - normal string.split would do. Actually, there is `os.path.split` as well, that, predating pathlib, would always do the samething:

```
In [6]: name = "/home/user/JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar"

In [7]: import os

In [8]: os.path.split(name)[-1]
Out[8]: 'JHN097567898_01102019_050514_svc_dc.tar'
```

And last (and in this case, actually least), the reason of the error is that you are on windows, and your `os.path.sep` character is `"\"` - this character alone is not a full regular expression, as the regex engine expects a character indicating a special sequence to come after the "\".  For it to be used withour error, you'd need to do:

```
 re.split(re.escape(os.path.sep), "myfilepath")
```

Comment: Instead of pathlib he could also use the os.path module, with os.path.basename() and os.path.dirname()

Comment: That is stated as well (in a further edit after you commented, likely), but in modern Python, `os.path` should be deferred in favor of pathlib.